# How to clean up this python output

Tags: python

I was trying to use a python module `textract` to extract the text from images and since the images contains so much noise the output i was getting is noise in addition to the actual text that i am interested in. Can someone suggest the code to best ways to clean up the output.

Here is my code:

```
>>> for i in glob.glob("*.jpg"):
...     print(textract.process(i))
```

Here is my output:

```
...






-s.

4â€˜-0-.r-v .-

5,14,45_18685-M

c.

.4








"V-0-an .-

5,14,44_17793-M


5,13,66

17951-N


5,13,65_17959-N
```

Basically what i want is the lines that starts with number "5" and nothing else. So i added a line to my code above but still it didn't work the way that i expected.

Here is the revised code

```
>>> for i in glob.glob("*.jpg"):
...     text = textract.process(i)
...     if text.startswith('5'):
...             print text
```

and the output from the revised code

```
5,13,66

17951-N


5,13,65_17959-N
```

Comment: Could you share the output of your revised code? It seems like that should get pretty close to the desired output.

Comment: i have now added the output from the revised code

Comment: thanks, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should try split the extracted text to lines first:

```
>>> for i in glob.glob("*.jpg"):
...     text = textract.process(i)
...     # Split text to multi lines
...     for line in text.split('\n'):
...         if line.startswith('5'):
...                 print line
```

Answer (score 0):

So, taking into account your latest output, I think you should do this:

```
for i in glob.glob("*.jpg"):
    text = textract.process(i).strip()
    if text.startswith('5'):
        print text
```

That will remove all leading and trailing whitespace from the output. It looks like there's a lot of trailing whitespace in your case which is causing extra lines to appear between each line.

Comment: Doesn't work as expected. Here is the ouput i am getting from your code - `5,13,66

17951-N
5,13,65_17959-N`. So i missing few lines there. Anyway i got the answer from @piglei and that works fine